# accessing Frames rendered in webbrowser control in C#.net

Tags: c#, html-frames

i need to get the links in a page rendered in webbrowser control in C#.net. Problem is that i think the page uses Frames that's why i cant get any links from webbrowser. how can i access or see those frames in the webbrowser control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [Frames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.frames.aspx) property: `webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames`

Comment: Note also that documents (and documents within frames) can contain iframes, which means that if the structure of the page you are parsing isn't known you would probably need to investigate this Frames property recursively.