# How to get the innerHTML of a webbrowser control in Silverlight after postback?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I've used a webbrowser control in Silverlight OOB application and binded it's source to a dynamic URI.

That URI loads a payment page and after I enter required details it postback and set some values in hidden HTML tags of rendered HTML page.

For example:

```
<html>
<body>
  <input type="hidden" id="fullResponse" value="Any Content Here" />
  <input type="hidden" id="transactionResponse" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" id="paymentFinishedSignal" value="done"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to read value of id="fullResponse" after postback.

I found a similar answer here: [accessing Frames rendered in webbrowser control in C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026743/accessing-frames-rendered-in-webbrowser-control-in-c-net)
but I'm looking for one specific to Silverlight.

I also found a way to read innerHTML of webbrowser control: `webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml` but **Document** property is not available in Silverlight's webbrowser control.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.